# Get table name from create table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

Now I want to get table name from create table sql, such as

```
CREATE TABLE `engineers` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX(`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS .....
```

Comment: Why did you tag `ruby` ?

Comment: Please explain - do you have this CREATE statement as text in a variable? What? If so this is not a SQL question, more of a string parsing question.

Comment: Because I will implement this in my ruby program @Viktor , I know regex will get this.But I also want to there is any other way achieve this by ruby

Comment: @Nikkorian Yes,I did have a string variable recording this sql.

Comment: Then based on the MYSQL definition of a CREATE statement (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html),  there are only two possible tokens before the table name, TABLE and EXISTS, as you have in your question. It's just a question of parsing the string based on these. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: @Nikkorian yep, you are right

Comment: Time of birth is always critical with engineers.

Comment: You have two answers offered. If either met your needs you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can query `information_schema` of your database server then you can access your table name from the result of following query.

```
select  table_name,
        create_time AS `Time` 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = @dbName
order by create_time desc 
limit 1
```

This should be run right after table creation is done

```
table_name      Time
table_20200815  15.08.2020 12:06:25
```

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/DEUPB27836)

Answer (score 1):

This is in php, but should be easy to convert to ruby. Assuming the Create statement is in $sql...

[EDITED to allow for "(" to follow tablename, and fix parameter order in strpos()]

```
    $tablename = trim(substring($sql,strpos($sql,"TABLE IF NOT EXISTS") === 0 ? strpos($sql,"TABLE") + 5 : strpos($sql,"TABLE IF NOT EXISTS") + 20));
    $tablename = substring($tablename,0,strpos($tablename,strpos($tablename," ") < strpos($tablename,"(") ? " " : "("));
```

Then test for and strip backticks if there are any.